# Table to be contained within a div element

Tags: html, css

I created a form which takes a word(s) and then have it search across Twitter for 20 most recent tweets containing that word(s).

Originally, the form is contained in a div element. When the form receives an input, it will print out those 20 tweets in a table.

The issue I'm having is that when the table is printed out, it stretches the div element size. So what I would get is a div element where its height would match the table height. I tried using the `overflow` CSS attribute but it doesn't seem to work.

Basically, what I would like to achieve here is to have a table of numerous rows contained in a div element without stretching the size of the div element.

Is there a way I could do that? Any examples?

HTML code:

```
<section class="wrapper">
<div class="header"><h2>Search for tweets</h2></div>

<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="<%= h @params[:search] %>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<% unless @tweets.nil? %>
    <table class="landingpage">
        <tr>
            <th width="15%">User</th>
            <th width="40%">Text</th>
            <th width="17%">Date</th>
            <th width="10%">Retweets</th>
            <th width="10%">Favourites</th>
        </tr>
        <% @tweets.each do | tweet | %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= tweet.user.screen_name %></td>
            <td><%= tweet.text %></td>
            <td><%= tweet.created_at %></td>
            <td><%= tweet.retweet_count %></td>
            <td><%= tweet.favorite_count %></td>
        </tr>

        <% end %>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

CSS code:

```
.wrapper {
position:absolute;
top:13%;
left:24%;
margin-top: 5px;
display:table;
margin-left: 10px;
background-color: #92ff6c;
width: 800px;
height: 650px;
border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
overflow-x:auto;
}

.landingpage {
border-collapse: collapse;
width:95%;
margin-top: 2%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
table-layout:fixed;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: @isherwood my code has been added

Comment: Rendered HTML would be better than server-side code for a CSS question. Here's the start of a demo. Please modify it so that it demonstrates the problem, and add the link to your quesiton. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hy8bL3mq/

Answer (score -1):

You might consider looking into flexboxes. Check out this resource for a quick rundown:

http://flexboxin5.com/